# AutoMapper: Issues mapping an ImmutableHashSet

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-9

I'm trying to `Map` and `ReverseMap` an `ImmutableHashSet` property to an `ICollection` using `AutoMapper`.

The Automapper successfully maps the `ImmutableHashSet` property to `ICollection` but it  fails to map the `ICollection` back to `ImmutableHashSet`

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

Consider I have  `Order` and `OrderItem` class as below:

```
public class Order
{
    private HashSet<OrderItem> _orderItems;

    public Order()
    {
        _orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
    }

    public ImmutableHashSet<OrderItem> OrderItems
    {
        get => _orderItems.ToImmutableHashSet();
        private set => _orderItems = value.ToHashSet();
    }

    public void AddOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        _orderItems.Add(orderItem);
    }

    public void RemoveOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        _orderItems.Add(orderItem);
    }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public OrderItem(int orderId, string orderName)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        OrderName = orderName;
    }

    public int OrderId { get; private set; }


    public string OrderName { get; private set; }
}
```

The `Order` and `OrderItem` classes need to be mapped to below `OrderDto` and classes

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItemDto
{

    public int OrderId { get; set; }


    public string OrderName { get; set; }
}
```

The `OrderProfile` class below defines the Automapper Profile to map `Order` to `OrderDto` and visa-versa.

```
public class OrderProfile : Profile
{
    public OrderProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
            .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemDto>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class OrderItemDto
{

    public int OrderId { get; set; }


    public string OrderName { get; set; }
}
```

Code to map and reverse map the `Order` and `OrderDto` classes:

```
private static void Map()
{
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new OrderProfile());
    }).CreateMapper();

    var order = new Order();
    order.AddOrderItem(new OrderItem(1, "Laptop"));
    order.AddOrderItem(new OrderItem(2, "Keyboard"));

    // This code maps correctly
    var orderDto = mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);

    // This is where I get an exception
    var orderMappedBack = mapper.Map<Order>(orderDto);
}
```

On mapping the `Order` `object` from `OrderDto`, I get the following exception:

> ```
> System.ArgumentException: System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1[ReadOnlyCollectionDemo.OrderItem]
> needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.
> (Parameter 'type') at lambda_method(Closure , OrderDto , Order , ResolutionContext )
> ```

Any pointers to help fix this issue is highly appreciated.

**Update**

I somehow got it working through custom `Converter`. But I really do not know how it worked. I updated my mapper configuration as follows:

```
 var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new OrderProfile());
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof(ICollection<>), typeof(ImmutableHashSet<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(HashMapConverter<,>));
        }).CreateMapper();
```

My `HashMapConverter` class:

```
public class HashMapConverter<TCollection, TImmutableHashSet> 
        : ITypeConverter<ICollection<TCollection>, ImmutableHashSet< TImmutableHashSet>>
    {
        public ImmutableHashSet< TImmutableHashSet> Convert(
            ICollection<TCollection> source,
            ImmutableHashSet< TImmutableHashSet> destination,
            ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return ImmutableHashSet<TImmutableHashSet>.Empty;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm just returning an empty `ImmutableHashSet`, however, to my surprise the `OrderDto` is now successfully mapped back to `Order` with the correct number of `OrderItems` `Count`. I would have expected the `Count` to be 0 since I'm returning an empty `HashSet`. I suspect it is working because `OrderItem` and `OrderItemDto` are also mapped through `AutoMapper`.

I would like to confirm my hypothesis and know if this is a correct approach.

Comment: AM doesn't consider `ImmutableHashSet` in any way, so you'll have to handle that yourself using a custom type converter.

Comment: Try CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
        CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemDto>(); CreateMap<OrderDto, Order>();
        CreateMap<OrderItemDto, OrderItem>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out mapping an `ImmutableHashSet` with the collection was not as straightforward as it seems. However, this made me realize that maybe I was not solving the correct problem. All I wanted was to ensure that my `OrderItem` `HashSet` cannot be modified outside the `Order` class. I could easily achieve this by returning an `IReadOnlyCollection`.

Here's my updated `Order` class:

```
public class Order
{
    private HashSet<OrderItem> _orderItems;

    public Order()
    {
        _orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> OrderItems
    {
        get => _orderItems.ToImmutableHashSet();
        private set => _orderItems = value.ToHashSet();
    }

    public void AddOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        _orderItems.Add(orderItem);
    }

    public void RemoveOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        _orderItems.Add(orderItem);
    }
}
```

`IReadOnlyCollection` not only helps me to resolve the Automapper issue but in addition to this, it does not expose the `Add` method. Hence, a user cannot accidentally call `order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem)` method outside the `Order` class.

Comment: (You don't need to wait for the bounty to expire before adding a self-answer - as the bounty setter you get to choose who to send it to anyway).

Answer (score 2):

In my similar example I did not get expected values back but an empty collection, so you are better of completing the conversion function with

```
public class HashMapConverter<TCollection, TImmutableHashSet>
: ITypeConverter<ICollection<TCollection>, ImmutableHashSet<TImmutableHashSet>>
{
    public ImmutableHashSet<TImmutableHashSet> Convert(
        ICollection<TCollection> source,
        ImmutableHashSet<TImmutableHashSet> destination,
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var hs =new HashSet<TCollection>(source);
        return ((IEnumerable<TImmutableHashSet>)hs).ToImmutableHashSet<TImmutableHashSet>();
        //return ImmutableHashSet<TImmutableHashSet>.Empty;
    }
}
```

instead of returning empty;